# Pair two elements in a list and make a conditional statement to see if the pairs are equal to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this homework assignment and seem to be stuck on this question.

> Write a function that takes, as an argument, a list called aList. It returns a Boolean True if the list contains three pairs of integers, and False otherwise.

Example:

```
>>>threePairs([5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4])
False

>>>threePairs([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
True
```

I've tried using indexes and I don't really know how to slice so I'm stuck in figuring out how I make those pairs equal to each other in the condition so it is True.

This is what I had previous to deleting it and trying again.

```
def threePairs(aList):
    if [0] == [1] and [2] == [3] and [4] == [5]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to slice, you need index access (as a side note, you should ask your teacher if they've ever heard of `pep8`, `three_pairs(mylist)` would be far better):

```
def threePairs(aList):
    if aList[0] == aList[1] and aList[2] == aList[3] and aList[4] == aList[5]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But if you're ever returning `True` and `False` like this, you can just return the result of the comparison:

```
def threePairs(aList):
    return aList[0] == aList[1] and aList[2] == aList[3] and aList[4] == aList[5]
```

Though as other answers allude - your examples are not well defined. What if you have:

```
>>> threePairs([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

Should that return `True`, or `False`?

Comment: Wow that was really simple. Thank you. It makes it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: You were close! You probably just missed the part in your lectures about index access on a list.

Answer (score 3):

You could `zip` the a sliced list with itself one position ahead, with steps equal to `2` to get adjacent elements. Then feed that to [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with the condition you need:

```
def threePairs(l):
    return all(i == j for i,j in zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) simply takes an element from each of the iterables supplied and returns it as a tuple until one of the sequences is exhausted.

So, for example, if `l = [5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4]` and `zip` is used with `zip(l[::2], l[1::2])` you'd have:

```
# l[::2] = [5, 3, 1]
# l[1::2] = [6, 2, 4]
print(list(zip(l[::2], l[1::2])))
[(5, 6), (3, 2), (1, 4)]
```

Comment: @Wiggs try this: `>>> help(zip)`

Comment: @Wiggs apart from `help(zip)` I've tried to water down usage of `zip` here with an example list. You could also click the link I added for zip that takes you to the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'll be sure to look at them :)

Answer (score 2):

How about making a [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and check how many "pairs" you've got:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: def has_pairs(l, n):
            return sum(value / 2 for value in Counter(l).values() 
                       if value % 2 == 0) == n 

In [3]: has_pairs([5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4], 3)
Out[3]: False

In [4]: has_pairs([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 3)
Out[4]: True
```

Works for a list with any length and any input number of pairs.

Instead of using a `sum()` to count all the pairs, you can iterate over the counter one value at a time and have an *early exit* if number of pairs reaches or exceeds the input number of pairs.

Answer (score -1):

```
def threepairs(aList):
    counter = 0
    for element in aList:
        if counter >= 3:
            return True
        if element % 2 == 0:
            counter += 1
    return False
```